# How to access instance variable from a block

Tags: ruby

I have a pretty lame question regarding ruby. I have a following code:

```
@node          = Node.find(params[:id])
@similar_nodes = Tire.search 'nodes', load: true do
  query do
    fuzzy_like_this @node.title
  end
end
```

The problem is, that, for some reason, i can't access `@node` variable in `fuzzy_like_this` line. It returns `nil` even if Node has been found and i can access it in the second line. Can you please give me any advice why is that happening and what can i do to understand that behaviour better? I don't even know how to search for that.

---

Edit: Sorry for the typo in the title, ofcourse it should not be a "global" variable but instance variable.

Comment: Ican't see any global variables...

Comment: edit added. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables starting with '@' aren't global; they are instance variables. This means that they belong to a particular object, being (mostly) inaccessible from others.

What seems to be happening is that the `search` method is changing the context of execution (probably via [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval)/[`instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec)), which means that, inside the block, your `self` isn't the same, and you won't have access to the same instance variables.

A simple workaround is to use a local variable instead:

```
node           = Node.find(params[:id])
@similar_nodes = Tire.search 'nodes', load: true do
  query do
    fuzzy_like_this node.title
  end
end
```

Then, if you really need `node` to be an instance variable, you can assign it later:

```
@node = node
```

Answer (score 2):

Node is an instance variable, not a global. Since the block may be (in this case, is) executed in the context of another object, your ivars aren't there. Assigning the ivar value to a local name should work, as locals are lexically scoped.

tl;dr: 
`node = @node`, use local `node` within block.

Comment: Yes.. This is the exact reason.. Good catch!